# Python keeps generating syntax errors

Tags: python, syntax

This line had an error:

```
 print('Already built: ' + str(deletedDirs) + ' servers')
```

On 't' in the word print.
I deleted this one and then the line below it had a syntax error:

```
time.sleep(timeToSleep)
```

On 'e'
And so on.... Help me please. It worked yesterday but today it does not.

Comment: python is not generating syntax errors. You are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line *before* the statement is missing a closing parenthesis, or curly or square bracket.

The lines you keep deleting are not the problem, but Python doesn't know this until it discovers that that next line makes no sense when it was looking for a comma or closing parenthesis instead.

Demo; there should be **two** closing parenthesis:

```
>>> some_function(str('with additional arg, but missing closing parens')
... print('Oops?')
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    print('Oops?')
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check the file encoding
2. check the indents